# Using wait_for simultaneously for multiple conditions

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have 2 different `wait_for` conditions: is it possible to wait for one of the 2 conditions ?

1st: Wait for a file that will be created in `/path/to/file/.dbSetupSuccess`

```yaml
  wait_for:
    path: "/path/to/file/.dbSetupSuccess"
    timeout: 7200
    delay:   3
```

2nd: Wait for a string in a file

```yaml
  wait_for:
    path: "/var/lib/pgsql/11/data/pg_hba.conf"
    search_regex: hostssl(\s*)mydb(\s*)mydbuser(\s*)0.0.0.0/0(\s*)cert
    timeout: 7200
    delay:   3
```

I'm trying to combine them. It should stop waiting for two of them if `.dbSetupSuccess` is created or related line is added to `pg_hba.conf` file. Is it possible with `wait_for` or do I have to use `loop:` and `until:` with registers?

Comment: have you read my solution?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, it is a good solution but it didn't solve my problem. Because I'm trying to apply it for backward compatibility, it was waiting for a line but now it will wait for a file. I wanted to provide a backward compatibility by waiting also for the line as optional, so new Ansible would be compatible with old product. Old products doesn't have this kind of python script, too.

Comment: so you have to build a specific module in python and include it in ansile

Comment: I have added an empty file to the product. If it exists, I'm using new wait_for. If it doesn't exist, I'm using old wait_for option. This was the easiest way I think.

Comment: if you know python, you could do what you want in module..

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution, you have to adapt to your problem:

i create a python script, i put it in files folder:

this script tests only if 2 files are presents if one is present the task stops to check...

i have just adapted the code source found on github: [wait_for](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/wait_for.py)

```
import datetime
import errno
import math
import os
import re
import time
import sys

def check_fileExist(path):
    try:
        os.stat(path)
    except OSError as e:
        # If anything except file not present, throw an error
        if e.errno != 2:
            #elapsed = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - start
            return  {"rc": "error"}
        # file doesn't exist yet, so continue
    else:
        # File exists.  Are there additional things to check?
        return {"rc": 0}
   
    return {"rc": "1"}

def main():
    timeout = 10
    delay = 0
    state = 'present'
    paths = ["./test03", "./test02"]
    search_regex = ''
    msg = "bonjour"

    if search_regex is not None:
        compiled_search_re = re.compile(search_regex, re.MULTILINE)
    else:
        compiled_search_re = None

    start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    end = start + datetime.timedelta(seconds=timeout)
    while datetime.datetime.utcnow() < end:
        err = False
        for path in paths:
            result = check_fileExist(path)
            if result["rc"] == 0:
                print(path + " found")
                sys.exit(0)
            elif result["rc"] == "1":
                if err:
                    time.sleep(1)
                else:
                    err = True
            else:
                sys.exit(1)
    print( ','.join(paths) + " error") 
    print( "time finished", file=sys.stderr) 
    sys.exit(0)
    sys.exit(1) # if no ingore_errors -> fatal error


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**playbook:**

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - name: Run items 
      script: waitfile.py
      args:
        executable: python3
      ignore_errors: true
      register: result



    - name: display
      debug:
        msg: "{{ result }}"
```

**output when found**

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "./test02 found\n",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "./test02 found"
        ]
    }
}
```

**output when not found:**

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "stderr": "time finished\n",
        "stderr_lines": [
            "time finished"
        ],
        "stdout": "./test03,./test02 error\n",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "./test03,./test02 error"
        ]
    }
}
```

its jsut an example, you could modify to add args, or even create a new module with your arguments...